# How to update the value of a field in a custom class object

Tags: c#, windows, class, xaml

I am trying to alter the value in a class object.Is there any of doing that.I am trying this to show the update dynamically in UI.(xaml)

My class:

```
 public class Students
 {
    public int id;
    public string Name;
    public int Age; 
 }


//Students studs = new Students();
public ObservableCollection<Students> studs = new ObservableCollection<Students>();
Students studs_temp = sender as Students; // Read data in tapped function
int index = studs.IndexOf();
//Here I need to alter the Age of Student in studs where the id
 is equal to  id in studs_temp.
```

Comment: what is problem in assigning you can assing like stud1.age = stud2.age....

Comment: I had several objects add to studs and i need to edit a particular id's Age , Ans studs was declared globaly

Comment: First off you may want to rename your class to `Student` meaning one instance is exactly one student. Thus you see that you´ll need another structure to store a list of students, e.g. a `List<Student>` in which you can search for that student with a given `ID`.

Comment: Sry .. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int id;
    public string Name;
    public int Age; 
}
```

And within your consuming method:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
// ...
// populate your list
// ...

// select the student with a particular ID
Student s = students.Single(x => x.id == myID);
// now alter the age of that student
s.Age = 23;
```